# How to assign a variable for each single permutation?

Tags: python, variables, combinations, permutation, circular-permutations

I'm using the code below to find the permutations.

```
from itertools import permutations  
seq = permutations(['1','2','3'])  
print(seq)  
for p in list(seq):  
print(p)
```

Output:

```
('1', '2', '3')
('1', '3', '2')
('2', '1', '3')
('2', '3', '1')
('3', '1', '2')
('3', '2', '1')
```

How can I let python automatically assign a variable for each permutation as shown below ?

```
p1=('1', '2', '3')
p2=('1', '3', '2')
p3=('2', '1', '3')
p4=('2', '3', '1')
p5=('3', '1', '2')
p6=('3', '2', '1')
```

I am not sure what to do to make it automatically assign variables for the permutation. because I am trying to use these variables in the next step.

Comment: You can't (in general) and you **shouldn't**. Use a **list**. Don't dynamically create variables

Comment: Its unlikely you want to have those variables. What is your next step?